# How to set value for textarea in angular 7

Tags: angular

I use angular 7 form in following way. When I try to use patchValue for textarea element it doesnt set any value.

```
  mainBlockIdeaForm = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    caption: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });
```

```
<form [formGroup]="mainBlockIdeaForm">

<div class="form-group input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="caption" formControlName="caption"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="title" formControlName="title"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <textarea class="form-text-control" placeholder="description"  formControlName="description"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
```

```
    this.mainBlockIdeaForm.patchValue({
      caption: this.idea.caption,
      title: this.idea.title,
      description: this.idea.description});
```

Comment: are you sure that `this.idea.description` has a value ?

Comment: Yes it has value

Comment: can you please show exactly where you are calling this part of code `this.mainBlockIdeaForm.patchValue({ ` ...  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :)

```
 this.mainBlockIdeaForm.patchValue({description: 'SG'});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you actually update your form control, but basically you can do something like :

```
this.mainBlockIdeaForm.get('description').setValue('your value');
```

And your textarea will be updated.

Comment: Meanwhile I use bootstrap framework. I may have impact that the value not appear?

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea style="background-color:black;color:white;" [(ngModel)]='someValue' rows="30" cols="120">
```

the **NgModel** Will help Your Demand . and if You want it through form Control  then use the code

or

description: new FormControl(data ?data : null ,{}),
    in html

or 
using Form Controls

```
this.mainBlockIdeaForm.controls.description.setValue("Required value");
```

live Example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-4ssfml

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.mainBlockIdeaForm.controls.description.setValue(this.idea.description);
```

Comment: Meanwhile I use bootstrap framework. I may have impact that the value not appear?