# setting value of textarea in angular forms by javascript

Tags: angular, forms, selenium-webdriver, angular-forms

The following don't seem to be working for angular forms

```
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).value = "some text"
```

I have tried `.title`, `.name` or `.innerText` but none seem to work.

I also tried :

```
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'A'}));
```

or

```
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).focus()
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'A'}));
```

In the backend an `InputEvent` is being sent , but I can't figure out how to trigger it:

```
{
  isTrusted: true
  bubbles: true
  cancelBubble: false
  cancelable: false
  composed: true
  currentTarget: textarea#formly_14_textarea_description_1.form-control.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid
  data: "some text"
  dataTransfer: null
  defaultPrevented: false
  detail: 0
  eventPhase: 2
  inputType: "insertText"
  isComposing: false
  returnValue: true
  sourceCapabilities: null
  srcElement: textarea#formly_14_textarea_description_1.form-control.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid
  target: textarea#formly_14_textarea_description_1.form-control.ng- 
  touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid
  timeStamp: 1594480
  type: "input"
  view: null
  which: 0
[[Prototype]]: InputEvent
}
```

Here is a related question, but they are doing it via app source code, I am doing from external code(ie selenium/browser extension/dev console) so I don't have access to `ng-model` object.

[How to set value for textarea in angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627303/how-to-set-value-for-textarea-in-angular-7)

Here is html form that I am trying to interact with, on typing in the text area there don't seem to be any change in html. Js events are getting triggered but tracing that obfuscated code is beyond me.
The `textarea` with id=`formly_14_textarea_description_1` is what I am trying to set.

```
<form elementtiming="1634" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" novalidate="" class="spacer-xl-bottom ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">
    <div elementtiming="1635" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" class="aria-hidden-on-modalopen language-origin">
        <df-form elementtiming="1636" _ngcontent-tss-c128="">
            <form elementtiming="1643" novalidate="" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">
                <formly-form elementtiming="1644">
                    <formly-field elementtiming="1647" hide-deprecation="" class="input-field">
                        <vertical-view-wrapper elementtiming="1649">
                            <div elementtiming="1650" class="section form-group">
                                <div elementtiming="1651" class="spacer-ml-top spacer-xxs-bottom">
                                    <div elementtiming="1652" class="spacer-xxs-bottom section-title">
                                        <b elementtiming="1653">Extension name</b>
                                        <b elementtiming="1656" aria-hidden="true" class="win-color-fg-red"> *</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div elementtiming="1654" class="spacer-sm-bottom field-description">This is taken from your package manifest. To edit the text, update the manifest in your package and reupload it.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1655">
                                    <formly-field-input elementtiming="1657">
                                        <input elementtiming="1658" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine" type="text" disabled="disabled" aria-label="Extension name" id="formly_14_input_title_0" required="required">
                                    </formly-field-input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </vertical-view-wrapper></formly-field>
                    <formly-field elementtiming="1648" hide-deprecation="" class="textarea-field spacer-ml-top"><vertical-view-wrapper elementtiming="1659">
                            <div elementtiming="1660" class="section form-group">
                                <div elementtiming="1661" class="spacer-ml-top spacer-xxs-bottom">
                                    <div elementtiming="1662" class="spacer-xxs-bottom section-title">
                                        <b elementtiming="1663">Description </b>
                                        <b elementtiming="1666" aria-hidden="true" class="win-color-fg-red"> *</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div elementtiming="1664" class="spacer-sm-bottom field-description">Tell customers what your extension does.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1665">
                                    <formly-field-textarea elementtiming="1670">
                                        <textarea elementtiming="1671" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid" cols="1" rows="1" aria-label="Description, tell customers what your extension does." id="formly_14_textarea_description_1" required="required" maxlength="10000">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </formly-field-textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </vertical-view-wrapper>
                    </formly-field>
                </formly-form>
            </form>
        </df-form>
    </div><app-logos elementtiming="1637" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" label="Logos" _nghost-tss-c125="">
        <section elementtiming="1673" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="section aria-hidden-on-modalopen">
            <header-section elementtiming="1674" _ngcontent-tss-c125="">
                <header elementtiming="1675" class="section-header spacer-xxs-top">
                    <div elementtiming="1676" class="header-titles">
                        <div elementtiming="1677" class="titles-outer">
                            <div elementtiming="1678" class="titles-inner">
                                <span elementtiming="1679" class="section-title text-maxlines-1">
                                    <span elementtiming="1680" aria-required="true" class="h5" id="Extension logo_header_section">
                                        Extension logo
                                        <span elementtiming="1711" class="win-color-fg-red"> *</span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </header-section>
            <div elementtiming="1681" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="section-body">
                <div elementtiming="1682" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="row">
                    <div elementtiming="1683" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="col-xl-24">
                        <form elementtiming="1684" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div elementtiming="1685" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="row form-group-tall promotional-images">
                                <div elementtiming="1686" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="col-xs-24 sub-heading"><span elementtiming="1687" _ngcontent-tss-c125="">Recommended size: 300 x 300 pixels (minimum size 128 x 128 pixels) with aspect ratio 1:1</span>
                                    <button elementtiming="1688" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="btn-link btn-link-no-padding spacer-xxs-bottom" aria-label="Preview extension logo">Preview</button>
                                </div>
                                <form elementtiming="1689" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><input elementtiming="1690" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" type="file" name="fileuploader" class="fileuploader" accept=".png"></form>
                                <div elementtiming="1691" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <div elementtiming="1701" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="listing-image-container small-listing-container">
                                        <div elementtiming="1702" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="listing-image-inner rbtn">
                                            <div elementtiming="1703" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="image-box"><img elementtiming="1704" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="listingImage assetImage" alt="Extension Store logo logo.png" src="https://ingestionpackagesprod1.blob.core.windows.net:443/file/3001408932431984139?09%2f21%2f2023+17%3a34%3a56&amp;sv=2018-03-28&amp;sr=b&amp;sig=0Kyd3WdD5ViRUAP66fspl4A2AP5H%2bjy1nKNhlNO%2bX7g%3d&amp;se=2023-09-22T12%3a51%3a53Z&amp;sp=rl">
                                                <div elementtiming="1705" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="asset-overlay win-color-bg-0 color-alt"></div>
                                                <div elementtiming="1706" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="asset-action-icons">
                                                    <button elementtiming="1707" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="icon-button magnify" aria-label="Magnify">
                                                        <span elementtiming="1708" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="win-icon win-icon-ZoomIn win-color-fg-primary color-alt win-icon-size-ml">
                                                        </span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button elementtiming="1709" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="icon-button spacer-ml-left" aria-label="Delete">
                                                        <span elementtiming="1710" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="win-icon win-icon-Delete win-color-fg-primary color-alt win-icon-size-ml">
                                                        </span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div elementtiming="1696" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="image-box upload-placeholder win-color-bg-10" hidden="">
                                        <div elementtiming="1697" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="image-upload-placeholder-box assetImage"><img elementtiming="1698" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" src="/dashboard/microsoftedge/staticres/assets/uploadPlaceholder.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button elementtiming="1699" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="btn-link btn-link-no-padding btn-texticon ltr"><span elementtiming="1700" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="win-icon win-icon-Copy">
                                        </span>Duplicate this logo for all languages
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1692" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1693" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" class="bulleted-list win-color-fg-secondary text-caption">
                                        <li elementtiming="1694" _ngcontent-tss-c125="">
                                        </li>
                                        <li elementtiming="1695" _ngcontent-tss-c125="">
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <span elementtiming="1672" _ngcontent-tss-c125="" aria-label="Logo deleted successfully"></span>
    </app-logos><promo-tiles elementtiming="1638" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" size="Small" _nghost-tss-c126="">
        <section elementtiming="1712" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="section aria-hidden-on-modalopen"><header-section elementtiming="1713" _ngcontent-tss-c126="">
                <header elementtiming="1714" class="section-header spacer-xxs-top">
                    <div elementtiming="1715" class="header-titles">
                        <div elementtiming="1716" class="titles-outer">
                            <div elementtiming="1717" class="titles-inner"><span elementtiming="1718" class="section-title text-maxlines-1"><span elementtiming="1719" aria-required="true" class="h5" id="Small promotional tile_header_section">Small promotional tile</span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </header-section>
            <div elementtiming="1720" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="section-body">
                <div elementtiming="1721" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="row">
                    <div elementtiming="1722" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xl-24">
                        <form elementtiming="1723" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div elementtiming="1724" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="row form-group-tall promotional-images">
                                <div elementtiming="1725" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24 sub-heading">
                                    <p elementtiming="1735" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="remove-bottom-margin" id="Small_tile_size">Size: 440 x 280 pixels</p><he-button elementtiming="1726" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" appearance="link" class="btn-link spacer-xxs-bottom he-button" aria-label="Preview Small promotional tile" type="button">Preview</he-button>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1727" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1728" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="sortable listing-image-container row">
                                        <li elementtiming="1729" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="image-upload-container upload-placeholder win-color-bg-10" hidden="" aria-label="Screenshot image is uploading">
                                            <div elementtiming="1730" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="image-upload-placeholder-box thumbnail-image"><img elementtiming="1731" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" src="/dashboard/microsoftedge/staticres/assets/uploadPlaceholder.png"></div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div elementtiming="1736" _ngcontent-tss-c126="">
                                        <form elementtiming="1737" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><input elementtiming="1738" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" type="file" name="fileuploader" class="fileuploader" accept=".png"></form><he-button elementtiming="1740" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" appearance="secondary" class="he-button small-promo-tile" id="add_Small_tile_button" aria-label="Add image for Small promotional tile. Size: 440 x 280 pixels" type="button">Add Image</he-button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1732" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1733" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="bulleted-list win-color-fg-secondary text-caption hidden">
                                        <li elementtiming="1739" _ngcontent-tss-c126=""> 440 x 280 pixels </li>
                                        <li elementtiming="1734" _ngcontent-tss-c126=""></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </promo-tiles>
    <screenshots elementtiming="1639" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" label="Screenshots" _nghost-tss-c127="">
        <section elementtiming="1743" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="section aria-hidden-on-modalopen">
            <header-section elementtiming="1744" _ngcontent-tss-c127="">
                <header elementtiming="1745" class="section-header spacer-xxs-top">
                    <div elementtiming="1746" class="header-titles">
                        <div elementtiming="1747" class="titles-outer">
                            <div elementtiming="1748" class="titles-inner"><span elementtiming="1749" class="section-title text-maxlines-1"><span elementtiming="1750" aria-required="true" class="h5" id="Screenshot/s_header_section">Screenshot/s</span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </header-section>
            <div elementtiming="1751" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="section-body">
                <div elementtiming="1752" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="row">
                    <div elementtiming="1753" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="col-xl-24">
                        <form elementtiming="1754" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div elementtiming="1755" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="row">
                                <div elementtiming="1756" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="col-xs-24 sub-heading"><span elementtiming="1757" _ngcontent-tss-c127="">Upto 6 images showing how your extension works. Size: 1280 x 800 pixels or 640 x 400 pixels</span><button elementtiming="1758" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="btn-link btn-link-no-padding spacer-xxs-bottom" aria-label="Preview Screenshot/s">Preview</button></div>
                                <div elementtiming="1759" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1760" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="sortable listing-image-container row">
                                        <li elementtiming="1761" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="col-xs-8 image-upload-container upload-placeholder" hidden="" aria-label="Screenshot image is uploading">
                                            <div elementtiming="1762" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="image-upload-placeholder-box win-color-bg-10"><img elementtiming="1763" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" src="/dashboard/microsoftedge/staticres/assets/uploadPlaceholder.png"></div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1764" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1765" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" class="bulleted-list win-color-fg-secondary text-caption">
                                        <li elementtiming="1767" _ngcontent-tss-c127="">1280 x 800 pixels</li>
                                        <li elementtiming="1768" _ngcontent-tss-c127="">640 x 400 pixels</li>
                                        <li elementtiming="1766" _ngcontent-tss-c127="">Accepted file types: .png</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <he-button elementtiming="1769" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" id="add_screenshot_button" appearance="secondary" class="spacer-sm-bottom he-button" aria-label="Add image for Screenshot/s. Upto 6 images showing how your extension works. Size: 1280 x 800 pixels or 640 x 400 pixels" type="button">Add Image</he-button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <form elementtiming="1741" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <input elementtiming="1742" _ngcontent-tss-c127="" type="file" name="fileuploader" class="fileuploader" accept=".png">
        </form>
    </screenshots><promo-tiles elementtiming="1640" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" size="Large" _nghost-tss-c126="">
        <section elementtiming="1770" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="section aria-hidden-on-modalopen large-tile">
            <header-section elementtiming="1771" _ngcontent-tss-c126="">
                <header elementtiming="1772" class="section-header spacer-xxs-top">
                    <div elementtiming="1773" class="header-titles">
                        <div elementtiming="1774" class="titles-outer">
                            <div elementtiming="1775" class="titles-inner"><span elementtiming="1776" class="section-title text-maxlines-1"><span elementtiming="1777" aria-required="true" class="h5" id="Large promotional tile_header_section">Large promotional tile</span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </header-section>
            <div elementtiming="1778" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="section-body">
                <div elementtiming="1779" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="row">
                    <div elementtiming="1780" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xl-24">
                        <form elementtiming="1781" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div elementtiming="1782" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="row form-group-tall promotional-images">
                                <div elementtiming="1783" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24 sub-heading">
                                    <p elementtiming="1793" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="remove-bottom-margin" id="Large_tile_size">Size: 1400 x 560 pixels</p>
                                    <he-button elementtiming="1784" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" appearance="link" class="btn-link spacer-xxs-bottom he-button" aria-label="Preview Large promotional tile" type="button">Preview</he-button>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1785" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1786" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="sortable listing-image-container row">
                                        <li elementtiming="1787" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="image-upload-container upload-placeholder win-color-bg-10 large-promo" hidden="" aria-label="Screenshot image is uploading">
                                            <div elementtiming="1788" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="image-upload-placeholder-box thumbnail-image"><img elementtiming="1789" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" src="/dashboard/microsoftedge/staticres/assets/uploadPlaceholder.png">
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div elementtiming="1794" _ngcontent-tss-c126="">
                                        <form elementtiming="1795" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><input elementtiming="1796" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" type="file" name="fileuploader" class="fileuploader" accept=".png">
                                        </form>
                                        <he-button elementtiming="1798" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" appearance="secondary" class="he-button large-promo-tile" id="add_Large_tile_button" aria-label="Add image for Large promotional tile. Size: 1400 x 560 pixels" type="button">
                                            Add Image
                                        </he-button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1790" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="col-xs-24">
                                    <ul elementtiming="1791" _ngcontent-tss-c126="" class="bulleted-list win-color-fg-secondary text-caption hidden">
                                        <li elementtiming="1797" _ngcontent-tss-c126=""> 1400 x 560 pixels </li>
                                        <li elementtiming="1792" _ngcontent-tss-c126=""></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </promo-tiles>
    <div elementtiming="1641" _ngcontent-tss-c128="" class="aria-hidden-on-modalopen">
        <df-form elementtiming="1642" _ngcontent-tss-c128="">
            <form elementtiming="1645" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <formly-form elementtiming="1646"><formly-field elementtiming="1799" hide-deprecation="" class="input-field"><vertical-view-wrapper elementtiming="1801">
                            <div elementtiming="1802" class="section form-group">
                                <div elementtiming="1803" class="spacer-ml-top spacer-xxs-bottom">
                                    <div elementtiming="1804" class="spacer-xxs-bottom section-title">
                                        <b elementtiming="1805">YouTube video URL</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div elementtiming="1806" class="spacer-sm-bottom field-description"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1807"><formly-field-input elementtiming="1808">
                                        <input elementtiming="1809" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" aria-label="YouTube video URL" id="formly_16_input_urls.VideoUrl[0].url_0" pattern="^(https://(www\.)?youtu\.be/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]|_)+($|\?.*)|https://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]|_)+($|&amp;).*)" placeholder="Provide a valid URL">
</formly-field-input></div>
                            </div>
                        </vertical-view-wrapper>
                    </formly-field><formly-field elementtiming="1800" hide-deprecation=""><vertical-view-wrapper elementtiming="1810">
                            <div elementtiming="1811" class="section form-group">
                                <div elementtiming="1812" class="spacer-ml-top spacer-xxs-bottom">
                                    <div elementtiming="1813" class="spacer-xxs-bottom section-title">
                                        <b elementtiming="1814">Search terms</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div elementtiming="1815" class="spacer-sm-bottom field-description">Up to 7 terms. 30 character limit for each term. No more than 21 separate words across all search terms.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div elementtiming="1816"><app-search-terms elementtiming="1817" _nghost-tss-c149="">
                                        <form elementtiming="1818" _ngcontent-tss-c149="" novalidate="" class="listings-search-terms ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" aria-label="Add Search terms">
                                            <div elementtiming="1819" _ngcontent-tss-c149="" class="spacer-sm-bottom ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                                                <div elementtiming="1820" _ngcontent-tss-c149="" class="input-counter" title="30 Characters Left" data-counter="30">
                                                    <input elementtiming="1821" _ngcontent-tss-c149="" type="text" class="search-term-input full-width ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="last-search-item" aria-label="Search term
                1, 30 Characters Left" placeholder="Enter a search term" maxlength="30">
                                                </div>
                                                <button elementtiming="1822" _ngcontent-tss-c149="" role="button" class="btn-link btn-link-no-padding action-link spacer-xxs-left" disabled=""> Add Term </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </app-search-terms>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </vertical-view-wrapper>
                    </formly-field>
                </formly-form>
            </form>
        </df-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is `TEXTAREA_SELECTOR` ? is it ID or class?

Comment: @AshishMishra in  this example it's `'#formly_14_textarea_description_1'`.

Comment: Try to do it with sendKeys first if that's an option

Comment: @pguardiario for selenium I guess that's an option what about the other external ways that I mentioned. `sendKeys` of selenium is nothing but abstraction of `dispatchEvent` in plain js

Comment: You need add the event `input`, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044601/manipulate-html-element-by-click-on-a-children-element-with-a-directive/77075879#77075879)

Comment: @Eliseo not sure I understand what I would do after adding an `eventListener`, I don't know what function to call inside it. can you help me with the code? Feel free to post as answer if comment area is too small for it.

Comment: ::glups:: Sorry, I indicate wrong the link, the correct is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128300/angular-16-how-make-reactive-form-recognize-an-input-change-when-the-element-wa/77128799#77128799), see also the NOTE to another approach.

Comment: @Eliseo great it works

Comment: @pguardiario That day I was on plain typescript as part of chrome extension (not on selenium) but later I tried with selenium and found selenium `sendKeys` too needs `dispatchEvent`, This answer suggests that too https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986041/865220 . at least my version at v4.1 needs. Ideally it should be build into the logic of `sendKeys` . Can you confirm if it's incorporated or not in latest release of selenium. if not why ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 - it shouldn't or else all angular sites would have broken e2e tests... There might be something strange about your case

Comment: @pguardiario can you explain bit more, as far my understanding all angular form will be failing `sendKeys`, what is that something strange you are talking about ?

Comment: @Eliseo can you confirm if all angular forms have this issue or there is something special in this case ?

Comment: @ishandutta - I've just never seen an issue with angular and sendKeys and I've done a lot of angular forms..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Eliseo ,

changing:

```
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).value = "some text";
```

to:

```
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).value = "some text";
document.querySelector(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR).dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

sufficed